# Array.length occasionally does not recheck the array length

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I have a relatively simple function in a Google Script which occasionally does not behave the way I expect.

I have an array of strings and a random number generator. When a random number is generated, it takes the array value at the index of the random number, splices it out, and returns it. This ensures that I only ever get a unique value from the array. The code is as follows:

```
function testFunction() {
      var array = [
     "Test String 1", "Test String 2", "Test String 3", "Test string 4"
      ];

     var randomNum = generateRandomNumber(array.length - 1,0);

     Logger.log(array.length);
     var arrayStringOne = array.splice(randomNum, 1);
     Logger.log(array.length);
     var arrayStringTwo = array.splice(randomNum, 1);
     Logger.log(array.length);
     var arrayStringThree = array.splice(randomNum, 1);
     Logger.log(array.length);
     return [arrayStringOne,arrayStringTwo,arrayStringThree];
     }

function generateRandomNumber(maximum, minimum){
         var randomNumber = Math.round(Math.random() * (maximum - minimum) + minimum);
         return randomNumber;
         }
```

While I normally see the array length deducted properly (i.e., the array goes from 4 to 3 to 2 to 1 when this is run), occasionally it stops shortening halfway through, and I'm not sure why (so I will see the array length be 4,3,3,3 instead of 4,3,2,1).

Here's a screenshot of my logs when it does this:

[image]

Versus what it should do:

[image]

Interestingly, it also doesn't always break in the same place. Sometimes it will break further down the line, and I will see an array length like 4,3,2,2 returned:

[image]

Additionally, when `generateRandomNumber(array.length - 1,0)` is not assigned as a variable, and is instead placed directly into the splice method this doesn't seem to ever occur, as in this example code:

```
function testFunction() {             
    var array = [
        "Test String 1", "Test String 2", "Test String 3", "Test string 4"
    ];

         Logger.log(array.length);
         var arrayStringOne = array.splice(generateRandomNumber(array.length - 1,0), 1);
         Logger.log(array.length);
         var arrayStringTwo = array.splice(generateRandomNumber(array.length - 1,0), 1);
         Logger.log(array.length);
         var arrayStringThree = array.splice(generateRandomNumber(array.length - 1,0), 1);
         Logger.log(array.length);
         return [arrayStringOne,arrayStringTwo,arrayStringThree];
         }

function generateRandomNumber(maximum, minimum) {
         var randomNumber = Math.round(Math.random() * (maximum - minimum) + minimum);
         return randomNumber;
         }
```

This is a non-essential script for me, and this "workaround" is a fine replacement, but I'm curious as to why this is happening. Initially I would have imagined that once I assigned the variable:

```
var randomNum = generateRandomNumber(array.length - 1,0);
```

Javascript (or Apps script) would have just checked the array length once, and never again, but the fact that it mostly works and only sometimes breaks (or breaks in different places) has me stumped. Is this a quirk of Javascript or Apps script? What is causing this? Is it possible there's some sort of race condition here, where the array length is being checked before the previous `splice` method has finished updating the array? Why does this not seem to happen when it's not assigned as a variable?

I'm most interested in any thoughts or comments here.

Comment: Let `randomNum` be `3 // == (array.length - 1)` so you will remove the last element with the first `.splice()`. On the next `.splice()` `randomNum` is still `3` but the `array` now has only 3 elements. Hence `.splice()` doesn't remove an element from the array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right now `randomNum` is the same for each `splice ()` call, since it is only set once at the beginning.  As @Andreas suggests, if it is `3` at the start, then it will only remove an element once. In fact you'll only ever get your desired output if it is 0. Try making `randomNum` a function:

```
var randomNum = function () {
    return generateRandomNumber(array.length - 1,0);
}
```

Comment: Hmm, This is as I was expecting, as mentioned in my original question. I guess what threw me was when it worked sometimes, and didn't otherwise. I never considered that it was due to the random number generator only sometimes throwing up a value that was bigger then the array,

Comment: @HDCerberus The random number generator isn't the source of the problem. It's because you're using the same number more than once for `.splice()`